# Comment from user with reputation of 1

Tags: support, reputation, comments

Just curious how someone who seems to be a new user with reputation of 1 and not the OP has managed to post [a Comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67287/607160).

[Privileges](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) shows *50  comment everywhere  Leave comments on other people's posts*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He actually posted an answer - then a moderator converted it to a comment.

This isn't *especially* common, but it is an option for cases where an answer turns out to be particularly useful as a comment (but isn't in any way an answer).

Comment: @pnuts That was me.  I thought his counterexample of the search switch not working properly was worth a second look, despite being buried in a bit of cruft.